# How to create a boot program that will ask which Rescue Disk to load?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, usb, grub

Hello I have huge collection of rescue disks and live OSs. I have extracted them in my USB pendrive. I want "**boot program script**" that will ask on start which rescue program or live OS is to be loaded. **I have rescue disks as follows:-**

(i) AOSS(Malware Scanner)

(ii) AVG

(iii) Avira

(iv) Bitdefender

(v) Comodo

(vi) F-Secure

(vii) Kaspersky

**And Live Disks as follows:-**

(i) Ubuntu Studios 13.04

(ii) Active Boot Disk

(iii) ERD Commander.

And I will add more rescue disk later so please explain how you did assuming that I(asker) am novice with any other languages other than HTML and Batch Programming. I know that HTML have no-use in this project but I am completely not very sure. If you cannot explain me the whole matter then just tell me how can I add some more rescue disks in it(script)?

I again describes that I have extracted above listed rescue and Live OS iso images in my 8GB USB Pendrive. I want a Boot Program script which will ask which rescue program or live OS is to be loaded every time when I boot from my USB Pendrive.

I also check at some other resources on the internet but I did not understand it fully. - [Yahoo Voices (Click here to see this resource)](http://voices.yahoo.com/how-create-own-computer-programs-easy-455585.html?cat=19)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I make USB drive bootable and install multiple OSes from it?](http://superuser.com/questions/100133/can-i-make-usb-drive-bootable-and-install-multiple-oses-from-it), http://superuser.com/questions/154133, http://superuser.com/questions/159960, http://superuser.com/questions/338134, http://superuser.com/questions/448453, http://superuser.com/questions/525754 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grub` for that. I use the instructions at http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/ to create a bootable USB pendrive.

I put ISO images to `/iso/` directory on the pendrive and update `grub.cfg` accordingly. This way I have a pendrive from which I can boot various different versions of Kubuntu. Other live distributions can be booted in a similar way.

See also another answer: https://superuser.com/a/154204/92436.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is called multiboot usb. you can create one with some [unetbooting](http://michkhoo.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-ubuntu-1004-with-usb.html) if you follow [these steps](http://ininjas.com/forum/index.php?topic=3914.0).

Answer (score 0):

I use Multisystem, the best for me. And it can also handle MS Windows installation.
live cd : http://sourceforge.net/projects/multisystem/
Installation : http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install